# Can a hint be added to a Data Explorer query parameter?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Only camelCase can convey the meaning of a parameter, not even the underscore character.

For example, all I can do is:

> maxMonths: _____

But I'd like to be able to have a short sentence that describes the parameter, eg

> Maximum age of post in months (leave blank for all posts): ______

At the moment, I would have to have a massively long camelCase, which would be illegible:

> MaximumAgeOfPostInMonthsLeaveBlankForAllPosts

Is there a way/syntax to specify a hint like this?

---

If not, could it be added, something like:

```
##maxMonths[Maximum age in months]##
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I could see that being useful. As a temporary workaround you could describe the parameters in the description or in SQL comments, but let me grab some coffee and see what I can do about implementing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/21) that will implement this, albeit in a bit more of a "Markdown-ish" way than your suggestion:

[image: example of parameter label/description complete with typo]

<sup>Yes, there's a typo there. Shh. If you don't stare at it maybe it'll go away.</sup>

This will allow you to add better label text and an extended description (in the label title) using the syntax

```
-- param: <label text> <"optional description">
```

…where the comment can be anywhere in the query, as long as it's a single-line comment.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks!

Comment: This is my User ID. There are many like it, but this one is mine.